# Problem with a java webservices client with SOAP

Tags: java

Good morning, I have returned to work as a programmer after years away and I have had a problem with a java webservices client with SOAP.
The webservices is based on sending requests that contain an id (NIF) + a name and the server returns "identified", "not identified".
this is webservices description an [AEAT](https://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Declaraciones/Modelos_01_al_99/030_036_037/WS_Masivo/Manual_Tecnico_WS_Masivo_Calidad_Datos_Identificativos.pdf)

This is my code:

```
package main;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;

import es.gob.agenciatributaria.www2.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.burt.jdit.ws.VNifV2Ent_xsd.VNifV2EntContribuyente;
import es.gob.agenciatributaria.www2.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.burt.jdit.ws.VNifV2Sal_xsd.VNifV2SalContribuyente;
import es.gob.agenciatributaria.www2.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.burt.jdit.ws.VNifV2_wsdl.VNifV2;
import es.gob.agenciatributaria.www2.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.burt.jdit.ws.VNifV2_wsdl.VNifV2ServiceLocator;
import es.gob.agenciatributaria.www2.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.burt.jdit.ws.VNifV2_wsdl.VNifV2SoapBindingStub;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, ServiceException {
        System.out.println("Comprobar DNI");
        
        Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
         String nif = "0000000C";
         String nombre ="Carlos Carlos Carlos";
         byte[] bytes = nif.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         String nif8 = new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         bytes = nombre.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         String nombre8 = new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String url1 ="https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/BURT-JDIT/ws/VNifV2SOAP";
        String url2="https://www10.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/BURT-JDIT/ws/VNifV2SOAP";
        URL destino = null;
        try {
             destino = new URL(url2);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        //("000000C","CARLOS CARLOS CARLOS")
        VNifV2EntContribuyente VnEnCo[] = new VNifV2EntContribuyente[5];
        VNifV2EntContribuyente VnEnCo1 = new    VNifV2EntContribuyente(nif8,nombre8); 
        VnEnCo[0] = VnEnCo1;
        VNifV2SalContribuyente  VnSalCo[] = new VNifV2SalContribuyente[5];
        //Revisar constructores de services
        VNifV2ServiceLocator services= null;
        //  services =  new VNifV2ServiceLocator("http://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/burt/jd\r\nit/ws/VNifV2.wsdl",new QName("http://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/burt/jd\\r\\nit/ws/VNifV2.wsdl","Entrada"));
        services =  new VNifV2ServiceLocator();
        VNifV2SoapBindingStub VNIFSoapBindings;
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Servcies es: "+services);
            System.out.println("Destino es: "+destino);
            
            //VNIFSoapBindings = new VNifV2SoapBindingStub(destino,services);
            VNIFSoapBindings = new VNifV2SoapBindingStub(destino,services);
            VnSalCo = VNIFSoapBindings.VNifV2(VnEnCo);
            //System.out.println(VnSalCo[1].getResultado());
        } catch (AxisFault e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startDTD(DeserializationContext.java:1161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.doctypeDecl(AbstractSAXParser.java:342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.doctypeDecl(XMLDTDValidator.java:724)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.scanDoctypeDecl(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:666)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:924)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at es.gob.agenciatributaria.www2.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.burt.jdit.ws.VNifV2_wsdl.VNifV2SoapBindingStub.VNifV2(VNifV2SoapBindingStub.java:185)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:60)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:DESKTOP-HBCCQUL

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:701)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at es.gob.agenciatributaria.www2.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.burt.jdit.ws.VNifV2_wsdl.VNifV2SoapBindingStub.VNifV2(VNifV2SoapBindingStub.java:185)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startDTD(DeserializationContext.java:1161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.doctypeDecl(AbstractSAXParser.java:342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.doctypeDecl(XMLDTDValidator.java:724)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.scanDoctypeDecl(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:666)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:924)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    ... 10 more
```